# Plotly bar chart legend within subplot

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am wondering on how to make a legend based on the coloured bars rather than individual trace charts. In this case, the legend should be based on `'giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'`.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1, 
    cols=3, 
    subplot_titles=('Zoo1',  'Zoo2', 'Zoo3'))

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    y=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    x=[21, 15, 23],
    orientation='h',
    marker_color=["#00573C", '#9BD7BE', '#990012']),
    row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    y=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    x=[15, 31, 23],
    orientation='h',
    marker_color=["#00573C", '#9BD7BE', '#990012']),
    row=1, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    y=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    x=[11, 32, 23],
    orientation='h',
    marker_color=["#00573C", '#9BD7BE', '#990012']),
    row=1, col=3)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotly takes the last bar's color in each subplot and assigns it to the legend, which is the green. To solve this problem, you can change the way you build your subplot. I build each bar in each subplot individually to be able to display it in the legend as in the code below:

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

no_cols = 3
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1, 
    cols=no_cols, 
    subplot_titles=('Zoo1',  'Zoo2', 'Zoo3'))

y=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys', 'cat', 'dog'] 
x=[[15, 10, 6, 21, 43],[5, 10, 12, 21, 43],[30, 32, 23, 21, 44]] 
colors=["#00573C", '#9BD7BE', '#990012', '#008080', '#808080']

for i in range(1,no_cols+1):
    for value,animal,color in zip(x[i-1],y,colors):
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            y=[animal],
            x=[value],
            orientation='h',
            marker_color=color, 
            name=animal,
            showlegend= i==no_cols),
            row=1, col=i)
    
fig.show()
```

**Output:**
[image]